# C++ generate a random number between 0 and 100,000

Tags: c++, random, g++, solaris

what is the best way to do this? my compiler shows RAND_MAX = 32,767. so I'm curious how I can get a uniform random generation of values between 0 and 100,000?

Comment: Use the `<random>` header.

Comment: See [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and friends.

Answer (score 10):

I'll just put juanchopanza's comment into answer.

Use the `<random>` header if your compiler provides it (C++11).

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 10000);

std::cout << dis(gen) << std::endl;
```

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you cannot or do not want to do this, use a generator with enough bits (or combine 2 calls with shift and or), mask it to the next closest power of two (in your case `& 131071`, and reject any values greater than 100,000. Note that this has non-deterministic runtime, but it's the only straightforward way to get a non-biased distribution. Do NOT use the modulo operator.

Comment: @Damon: `& 131071` is of course the modulo operator `% 131072` in disguise, so it's a bit disingenuous to say never to use the modulo operator. Modulo (in any disguise) is biased whenever `(rand_max + 1) mod n > 0`.

Comment: @MSalters: Though in this case, the modulo operator in disguise really _isn't_ the modulo operator. Masking off the lowermmost N bits of an unbiased number does not bias those bits in any way. Which is really the one important difference. Certainly, having 15 bits in `RAND_MAX` and trying to magically pull 17 bits out of those won't work (that'd be "bias" if you want to call it that, but that's why I said one would need to combine two random numbers, e.g. something like `rand()|(rand()<<15)` to have enough random bits. The random bits are equally random whether your shift them or not, and ...

Comment: ... they're equally random (well, pseudo-random) whether you cut out the bottom 5 or 10 or 17 bits. If they aren't, then the random number generator is broken. Modulo (not on a power of two) on the other hand, _adds bias_ because it makes numbers wrap around. Even if the bits were (pseudo) random before, they won't be afterwards. Well, they're still "random", but some occur twice as often as others.

Comment: @Damon: Masking off the lower bits of an unbiased number definitely can create a bias. Trivially, given an unbiased number in the range [0,2] inclusive, masking off the lower bit will give 0 with probability 2/3. Given a number in the range [0,8], modulo 2 will again produce a bias (0 has chance 5/9) but modulo 3 will not (all results have chance 1/3). Why? `(8+1) modulo 2 > 0` but `(8+1) modulo 3 = 0`.

Comment: @MSalters: Except these _aren't_ numbers in the range [0,2] inclusive. They're numbers in the range [0,3] inclusive (or, more precisely, [0, some_power_of_two-1] inclusive (in this case 2^30-1). It's purely academic that you can contreive an example where masking off bits will cause a bias, it doesn't apply. A pseudo-random generator that isn't completely broken to begin with will not output such numbers (with bits that aren't equidistributed, such as the 0-bit in your example).

Comment: @Damon: Why are you assuming that? There's nothing in the standard that guarantees it; the best you get is that `RAND_MAX` is _at least_ 32767. Extrapolating from the assumption that "rand() isn't broken" is a bad idea; we know it usually is.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following function on some website a long time ago. The author claimed that function gives a good uniformity.

```
#define RS_SCALE (1.0 / (1.0 + RAND_MAX))
double drand(void) 
{
    double d;
    do {
       d = (((rand () * RS_SCALE) + rand ()) * RS_SCALE + rand ()) * RS_SCALE;
    } while (d >= 1); /* Round off */
    return(d);
}
```

As noted in a comment below this gives answer in range 0..1, so you have to multiply by 100000, i.e. `drand()*100000`.

Comment: This returns in `[0, 1)` failing to answer the question.

Comment: It should be noted that there aren't enough bits in `rand` (RAND_MAX being 32k) for this kind of thing. You will have "holes" in your distribution unless you do some hack like calling `rand` twice and combining the outputs.

Comment: @Damon I don't see why the holes would appear due to RAND_MAX=32k. If the distribution which gives drand() is uniform in the range [0,1) (and being without holes in this range), then its scaling with 100000 would also be uniform in the range [0,100000) and without holes, wouldn't it?

Comment: @IgorPopov: No, FP math does not follow the rules of real math. There are a finite number of `double` values between 0 and 1.0, and there are more `double` values between 0 and 100000.0. (Mathematically, both sets have equal size). By the pigeonhole principle, there must be holes. That said, `double` typically has IIRC about 2^62 values between 0 and 1. (Half of the numbers are positive , and half of the positive values are between 1 and infinity). Clearly you'd need 5 calls to `rand()` to get more than 60 bits, just to avoid holes.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably download and use a serious PRNG then, such as the ones available in the [Gnu Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html#Random-Number-Generation).

Comment: We already have standard serious PRNGs (and Boost has some as well).

Comment: @chris Recent C++ standards, yes.  His compiler, not necessarily.

Comment: Well, that's what Boost is for, really. You can almost assume every C++ developer has it.

Comment: @chris So we're both saying he may benefit from using an external library that does the job properly. It's a fine thing that he has choices.

Comment: can't use external libraries. It's for a school project, if the prof. doesn't have it on his syst. I cant have it on mine. I've just never needed a random number bigger then 10,000 before

Answer (score -1):

How I've found was to first, `#include <time.h>`, then you can write`srand(time(NULL));` to seed a value into the random function.  Then all you've got to do is use this line: `(rand() % 99999 + 1);`.  That should give you a random value in between 0 and 100,000.  You can also assign that to a variable if you need to: `int myVar = (rand() % 99999 + 1);`.  Hope that helps! (And I hope that I'm totally correct.  I'm still getting my CS degree and still learning C++, but I've done this before and it's worked.)

Comment: The max value that rand() will return is RAND_MAX which is normally 32,767.

Answer (score -3):

Here is your code:

```
100000.0f * ((float)rand() / 32767.0f)
```

This will produce random float from 0 to 100000 but you can use any positive number other than 100000 here.

**Update:**

Indeed (thanks to **psj**'s comment below) I've realized above covers ~1/3 of 0..100000 range.

Comment: Uniformness depends on rand() here so I am not sure either ;-)

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac I'm sure it's not.  It can only produce about a third of the integers in the range [0,100000].

Comment: All that does is scale a number random number your going to miss a large portion of the range.